# What does the lambda calculus have to say about return values?

Tags: r, return-value, lambda-calculus

It is by now a well known theorem of the lambda calculus that any function taking two or more arguments can be written through currying as a chain of functions taking one argument:

```
# Pseudo-code for currying
f(x,y) -> f_curried(x)(y)
```

This has proven to be extremely powerful not just in studying the behavior of functions but in practical use (Haskell, etc.).

Functions returning values, however, seem to not be discussed.  Programmers typically deal with their inability to return more than one value from a function by returning some meta-object (lists in R, structures in C++, etc.).  It has always struck me as a bit of a kludge, but a useful one.

For instance:

```
# R code for "faking" multiple return values
uselessFunc <- function(dat) {
   model1 <- lm( y ~ x , data=dat )
   return( list( coef=coef(model1), form=formula(model1) ) )
}
```

**Questions**

1. Does the lambda calculus have anything to say about a multiplicity of return values?  If so, do any surprising conclusions result?
2. Similarly, do any languages allow true multiple return values?

Comment: Why are you drawing a distinction between values and lists? Why isn't a list a suitable first-class value in your model?

Comment: A list is perfectly suitable.  My point is that a function can only return a single **object**.  If you want it to return multiple objects, you can trick it into doing so by returning a single object that holds other objects, then extract those objects.  I'm curious if there's any formalism surrounding multiple returned objects.

Comment: I know Matlab allows multiple return values, although I've never used it myself.

Comment: I really don't get the question - if you returned multiple objects they'd still need to be stored in some data structure.

Comment: @hadley I'm less interested in practical details (although as HongOoi points out implementations do exist) than in whether any surprising results come out of studying them formally.  Part of the problem is that I suspect any formal study would conclude that what most programmers do within a function is best separated into many functions (e.g. `lm` isn't a great function in mathy terms because it does many things), yet people return multiple values all the time and I don't know if there's any better way to think about it other than a function that does a few things and returns a few things.

Comment: @gsk3 I think you are going to deep into functional semantics - I honestly don't thinking studying lambda calculus is going to give you much insight into practical programming. Instead, I would recommend either the structure and interpretation of computing programming (free online), or Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming.  Those books are what most helped me to understand R.

Comment: @hadley Thanks.  SICP has been on my when-I-have-free-time list for awhile.  It just moved up a notch :-)

Comment: This might interest you. Stack based/concatenative languages seem to have a natural concept of returning multiple values http://evincarofautumn.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-concatenative-programming-matters.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia [page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lambda_calculus) on lambda calculus:

> Lambda calculus, also written as λ-calculus, is a formal system for function
>   definition, function application and recursion

And a function, in the mathematical [sense](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29):

> Associates one quantity, the argument of the function, also known as the input,
>   with another quantity, the value of the function, also known as the output

So answering your first question no, lambda calculus (or any other formalism based on mathematical functions) can not have multiple return values.

For your second question, as far as I know, programming languages that implement multiple return values do so by packing multiple results in some kind of data structure (be it a tuple, an array, or even the stack) and then unpacking it later - and that's where the differences lie, as some programming languages make the packing/unpacking part transparent for the programmer (for instance Python uses tuples under the hood) while other languages make the programmer do the job explicitly, for example Java programmers can simulate multiple return values to some extent by packing multiple results in a returned Object array and then extracting and casting the returned result by hand.

Comment: +1 for an interesting answer.  I disagree that the definition of a function implies that lambda calculus has nothing to say about multiple return values, though.  After all, the definition of a function precludes multiple inputs, and l.c. has something to say about those.

Comment: In the purest sense, lambda calculus does not allow multiple input values to a function - that's why we use currying, to "simulate" multiple input values

Comment: LIES! lambda calculus can have multiple return values by returning a function that given a church numeral(false, true, false false, ...), returns the element of the product. eg (\a. (\f. f('Hello')('World')). to get Hello, you call this returned function with (\a. \b. a) and (\a. \b. b) for "World". this can be automated by mapping integers to their product form. This gets hard since different sized products are different types, so we must standardize this to a fixed number of possible choices, eg bits. so the caller must be aware that the function returns an n sized product to get an element

Comment: @ÓscarLópez we use currying because products are impossible(difficult?) to properly generalize. Each product is its own type, so you cannot add anything to a product or remove anything from a product since (A,B),C and A, (B, C) are not the same as (A, B, C). This is why we fundamentally use lists for everything, even addition at a binary level treats numbers as a reversed lists(with first element being at the end, and remainder being at the front). What we think of as random access memory is nothing but a list of bytes, we avoid O(n) by using multiplexers, which make it logorithmic.

Answer (score 2):

A function returns a single value. This is how functions are defined in mathematics. You can return multiple values by packing them into one compound value. But then it is still a single value. I'd call it a vector, because it has components. There are vector functions in mathematics there, so there are also in programming languages. The only difference is the support level from the language itself and does it facilitate it or not.

Comment: a function's return may be a single value, but values are not necessarily scalars.  values can preserve arbitrary amount of state by wrapping it in a product. what you call vector is a very high level structure similar to an array. An array is nothing but a nested products of same size indexed by a multiplexer that abstracts away n if statements(where n is 8 * the number of bytes used to index the array, usually 32 bits, equivalent to 32 if statements). reminder: an if statement is \a. \b. \boolSelector . boolSelector(a)(b). where boolSelector is (\a. \b. a) or (\a. \b. b)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prevents you from having multiple functions, each one returning one of the multiple results that you would like to return.

For example, say, you had the following function in python returning a list.

```
def f(x):
  L = []
  for i in range(x):
    L.append(x * i)
  return L
```

It returns `[0, 3, 6]` for `x=3` and `[0, 5, 10, 15, 20]` for `x=5`. Instead, you can totally have

```
def f_nth_value(x, n):
  L = []
  for i in range(x):
    L.append(x * i)
  if n < len(L):
    return L[n]
  return None
```

Then you can request any of the outputs for a given input, and get it, or get `None`, if there aren't enough outputs:

```
In [11]: f_nth_value(3, 0)
Out[11]: 0

In [12]: f_nth_value(3, 1)
Out[12]: 3

In [13]: f_nth_value(3, 2)
Out[13]: 6

In [14]: f_nth_value(3, 3)

In [15]: f_nth_value(5, 2)
Out[15]: 10

In [16]: f_nth_value(5, 5)
```

Computational resources may be wasted if you have to do some of the same work, as in this case. Theoretically, it can be avoided by returning another function that holds all the results inside itself.

```
def f_return_function(x):
  L = []
  for i in range(x):
    L.append(x * i)
  holder = lambda n: L[n] if n < len(L) else None
  return holder
```

So now we have

```
In [26]: result = f_return_function(5)

In [27]: result(3)
Out[27]: 15

In [28]: result(4)
Out[28]: 20

In [29]: result(5)
```

Traditional untyped lambda calculus is perfectly capable of expressing this idea. (After all, it is Turing complete.) Whenever you want to return a bunch of values, just return a function that can give the `n-th` value for any `n`.

In regard to the second question, python allows for such a syntax, if you know exactly, just how many values the function is going to return.

```
def f(x):
  L = []
  for i in range(x):
    L.append(x * i)
  return L


In [39]: a, b, c = f(3)

In [40]: a
Out[40]: 0

In [41]: b
Out[41]: 3

In [42]: c
Out[42]: 6

In [43]: a, b, c = f(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-5480fa44be36> in <module>()
----> 1 a, b, c = f(2)

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

In [44]: a, b, c = f(4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-d2c7a6593838> in <module>()
----> 1 a, b, c = f(4)

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Lastly, here is an example from this [Lisp tutorial](http://learnlispthehardway.org/book/1-01-03-expressions/):

```
;; in this function, the return result of (+ x x) is not assigned so it is essentially
;; lost; the function body moves on to the next form, (* x x), which is the last form
;; of this function body. So the function call only returns (* 10 10) => 100
* ((lambda (x) (+ x x) (* x x)) 10)
=> 100
;; in this function, we capture the return values of both (+ x x) and (* x x), as the
;; lexical variables SUM and PRODUCT; using VALUES, we can return multiple values from
;; a form instead of just one
* ((lambda (x) (let ((sum (+ x x)) (product (* x x))) (values sum product))) 10)
=> 20 100
```

Answer (score -1):

I write this as a late response to the accepted answer since it is wrong!

Lambda Calculus does have multiple return values, but it takes a bit to understand what returning multiple values mean.

Lambda Calculus has no inherent definition of a collection of stuff, but it does allow you to invent it using products and church numerals.

pure functional JavaScript will be used for this example.

let's define a product as follows:

```
const product = a => b => callback => callback(a)(b);
```

then we can define church_0, and church_1 aka true, false, aka left, right, aka car, cdr, aka first, rest as follows:

```
const church_0 = a => b => a;
const church_1 = a => b => b;
```

let's start with making a function that returns two values, 20, and "Hello".

```
const product = a => b => callback => callback(a)(b);
const church_0 = a => b => a;
const church_1 = a => b => b;
const returns_many = () => product(20)("Hello");
const at_index_zero = returns_many()(church_0);
const at_index_one = returns_many()(church_1);

console.log(at_index_zero);
console.log(at_index_one);
```

As expected, we got 20 and "Hello".

To return more than 2 values, it gets a bit tricky:

```
const product = a => b => callback => callback(a)(b);
const church_0 = a => b => a;
const church_1 = a => b => b;
const returns_many = () => product(20)(
    product("Hello")(
        product("Yes")("No")
    )
);
const at_index_zero = returns_many()(church_0);
const at_index_one = returns_many()(church_1)(church_0);
const at_index_two = returns_many()(church_1)(church_1)(church_0);

console.log(at_index_zero);
console.log(at_index_one);
console.log(at_index_two);
```

As you can see, a function can return an arbitrary number of return values, but to access these values, a you cannot simply use result()[0], result()[1], or result()[2], but you must use functions that filter out the position you want.

This is mindblowingly similar to electrical circuits, in that circuits have no "0", "1", "2", "3", but they do have means to make decisions, and by abstracting away our circuitry with byte(reverse list of 8 inputs), word(reverse list of 16 inputs), in this language, 0 as a byte would be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] which is equivalent to:

```
const Byte = a => b => c => d => e => f => g => h => callback =>
    callback(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h);

const Byte_one = Byte(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(1); // preserves 
const Bit_zero = Byte_one(b7 => b6 => b5 => b4 => b3 => b2 => b1 => b0 => b0);
```

After inventing a number, we can make an algorithm to, given a byte-indexed array, and a byte representing index we want from this array, it will take care of the boilerplate.

Anyway, what we call arrays is nothing more than the following, expressed in higher level to show the point:

```
// represent nested list of bits(addresses) 
// to nested list of bits(bytes) interpreted as strings.
const MyArray = function(index) {
    return (index == 0)
        ? "0th"
        : (index == 1)
            ? "first"
            : "second"
        ;
};
```

except it doesnt do 2^32 - 1 if statements, it only does 8 and recursively narrows down the specific element you want. Essentially it acts exactly like a multiplexor(except the "single" signal is actually a fixed number of bits(coproducts, choices) needed to uniquely address elements).

My point is that is Arrays, Maps, Associative Arrays, Lists, Bits, Bytes, Words, are all fundamentally functions, both at circuit level(where we can represent complex universes with nothing but wires and switches), and mathematical level(where everything is ultimately products(sequences, difficult to manage without requiring nesting, eg lists), coproducts(types, sets), and exponentials(free functors(lambdas), forgetful functors)).